# Как называется алгоритм поиска оптимального распределения пар?

Tags: алгоритм

Помню что в институте нам давали алгоритм для решения следующей задачи:

> Есть N работников и N рабочих мест У каждого работника свои
>   индивидуальные показатели эффективности (пользы) на каждом из
>   возможных рабочих мест. Это можно представить в виде матрицы N на N.
>
> Как распределить всех работников по всем рабочим местам так, чтобы
>   суммарная эффективность была наивысшей? По одному рабочему на одно
>   место, все места и все рабочие должны быть разбиты на пары.

Не подскажете, как он называется?

Answer (score 2):

Это [Задача о назначениях](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

> В наиболее общей форме задача формулируется следующим образом:
>
> Имеется некоторое число работ и некоторое число исполнителей. Любой
>   исполнитель может быть назначен на выполнение любой (но только одной)
>   работы, но с неодинаковыми затратами. Нужно распределить работы так,
>   чтобы выполнить работы с минимальными затратами.

Одним из вариантов решения которой является [Венгерский алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC)